# How to add multiple objects to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

why the value of a[0].nil is 400. what should i do to set it to 200. thanks for the answer

```
a = new Array();
x = new Object();
str = "nil";

x[str] = 200;

a.push(x);

x[str] = 400;

a.push(x);

alert("1 = "+ a[0].nil);
alert("2 = "+ a[1].nil);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the value of a[0].nil is 400

Because `x` still points to old reference which you haven't changed (you only changed value of property inside it).

> what should i do to set it to 200

Simply before

```
x[str] = 400;
```

add this line

```
x = {}; //x = new Object();
```

Comment: @AhmadBudiU Glad to help. Accept and upvote the answer that has helped you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Because you are pushing reference of object `x`  to array `a`, not copy of that object.

After  modifying value of `x[str]`, a[0] reference pointing to updated object.

So in your code `a[0]`,`a[1]` and `x`pointing to same object. If you wish to add copy of `x` object in particular moment of code execution you have to clone your object `x` and push clone into array.

SO question [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) will help you in cloning js object. Also see article ["JavaScript: Passing by Value or by Reference"](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass) to get better idea of variable passing in javascript.

**Good Luck!**

Answer (score 0):

You should [**clone** object](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), with `Object.assing` as

> The **Object.assign()** method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
a = new Array();
x = new Object();
str = "nil";

x[str] = 200;

a.push(Object.assign({}, x));

x[str] = 400;

a.push(Object.assign({}, x));

document.write("1 = "+ a[0].nil);
document.write("2 = "+ a[1].nil);
```